# symfony 2 phpunit - how to untick checkbox in form field

Tags: symfony, phpunit

This should be an easy one but I can't find the answer anywhere.
I'm using Symfony 2 with phpunit to test my code.
Its easy enough to get phpunit to tick a checkbox while running tests:

```
$form['mycompanyname_companybundle_editsomethingtype[locked]']->tick();
```

But how do I get it to 'untick' a checkbox?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Field\ChoiceFormField::untick()`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/v2.1.2/src/Symfony/Component/DomCrawler/Field/ChoiceFormField.php#L104) for that. In your case it would be

```
$form['mycompanyname_companybundle_editsomethingtype[locked]']->untick();
```

Comment: Thanks gilden - as always, so obvious when you see the answer